# SQL Result showing same value only once

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting, output

maybe a simple question I am just not finding an answer for.
Im having an MySQL result like

```
Col1 | Col2    
A    | 1    
A    | 2   
B    | 1
```

I want it to output the following:

```
Col1 | Col2
A    | 1
     | 2
B    | 1
```

How can I do that? When using GROUP BY he still shows all "A"s in the first column, I want to be shown only once at first occurence.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select
  case when not exists (select 1 from tablename where col1 = t.col1 and col2 < t.col2) then t.col1 end col1,
  t.col2
from tablename t
order by t.col1, t.col2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7LEWzvswSHcLZSSujrA99Z/0).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| A    | 1    |
|      | 2    |
| B    | 1    |
```

Comment: That looks good - the other soultion may also work but this one I understand at least ;)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should do this type of formatting in the *application*, not in the database.  Why?  Your results are not really a valid table, because the definition of the second row depends on the first.  In a SQL table, each row should stand on its own.

But, you can do this, if you are careful:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then col1 end) as col1, col2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by col1, seqnum;
```

For this to work consistently, it is important that the outer `order by` matches the definition of `seqnum`.